# Issue in images on ms word rendered page in salesforce

Tags: visualforce

I am working on a requirement on which we are generating an ms word page using contentType="application/msword#file.doc".
We are displaying an image using  tag. when we open the file in windows, the image is being displayed in its original size. But when we open that file in mac, then the image is being displayed in very small size.
If anyone know the reason or solution for it. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Just a follow up for the question, I have solved it. We created a mediater page where we display all the images and on the click of a button we download our ms word page. Meanwhile clicking on the button we get the actual height and width of images and pass them to controller of ms word page and then set the height width .